# I want to open a file with open() function. Why am I getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python

I cannot open file.

```
open('file.txt')
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-f5022126236c>", line 1, in <module>
    open('file.txt')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Probably because you wrote `open = <some string>` somewhere before in your code, thus replacing the `open` builtin function with your string.

Comment: Did you previous assign `open` to something? Python has registered the variable `open` as a string

Comment: Remove the assignment, or just do `del open`.

Comment: I tried `del open` and it worked. Thanks!